# Why didn't Mike Mohring run in the Thüringen MP election?

Tags: election, germany

While discussing the election of Thomas Kemmerich one question came up: Why didn't Mike Mohring run in the third iteration of the MP election? He is from the third largest faction. Did they think that Grüne and SPD would rather vote for a FDP candidate than for a CDU candidate? I understand that having both an CDU and FDP candidate would have divided the conservatives's votes and likely Bodo Ramelow would have gained the simple majority.

The best explanation I had is that Mike Mohring has alienated the SPD and Grüne so much that they would never vote for him instead of the Linke, and so they hoped that the FDP candidate would gain their sympathy?

Or was it really some trick played to get elected via the AfD without having to officially announce it beforehand? And Mike Mohring did not want to do it but Thomas Kemmerich did not mind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mohring already [rejected](https://www.welt.de/politik/deutschland/article203790678/Thueringen-nach-der-Wahl-Keine-Kampfabstimmung-Mike-Mohring-gibt-auf.html) running back in November 2019 because the CDU only placed third in the election, which didn't give them a clear mandate to govern:

> „Wir haben mit Platz drei keinen Regierungsauftrag“, betonte sein Vize Mario Voigt. Der Wählerauftrag laute Opposition.

On the other hand, some in his faction such as Michael Heym didn't rule out collaboration with the fascist AfD even back then.

The SPD and Grüne supporting Mohring was never an option. For one, because they prefer Ramelow, and for another, a coalition of CDU/SPD/Grüne only has 35%, well below the required 50% (even if we add the 5% of the FDP). They would be dependent on votes from the AfD or Linke. The Linke, having gained much more votes, would insist on their own MP, and if CDU/FDP cooperate with the AfD, they wouldn't need SPD/Grüne.

The [official version of events](https://www.focus.de/finanzen/boerse/wirtschaftsticker/mohring-cdu-musste-in-thueringen-kandidaten-der-mitte-unterstuetzen_id_11631676.html) by the CDU/FDP is that they were merely supporting the candidate of the [so-called](https://www.zeit.de/politik/deutschland/2020-02/ministerpraesidentenwahl-afd-thueringen-wahl-landtag-thomas-kemmerich-fdp) ["middle"](https://www.merkur.de/politik/thueringen-wahl-ministerpraesident-landtag-umfrage-afd-fdp-cdu-spd-zusammenarbeit-zr-13529700.html) and not expecting to win, which may be another reason Mohring wasn't running (it may leave a bad impression if a relatively large party loses the election; the FDP on the other hand only gained 5% of the votes, so they loosing doesn't look as bad).

There is no public evidence for an official collusion between the fascist AfD and the CDU/FDP (yet), though many [theorized](https://www.volksverpetzer.de/aktuelles/afdp-geplant-hoecke-brief/) about the possibility of the FDP candidate being elected with the help of the AfD beforehand. This knowledge didn't stop the CDU/FDP from proceeding as they seemingly didn't expect such a large backlash to cooperation with fascists.